# Postgresql studio Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have installed the PostgreSQL Studio add on for Heroku and it appears under my database.  When I go into the app it shows the add on fine but when I click on the add on I get the error Service Temporarily Unavailable.  Any help for this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Postgresql Studio addon is currently having some issues -- this is a temporary problem. Just check back later.

Comment: Thank you it has been like this for 2 days so wasn't sure if it was them or if I had something configured somewhere incorrectly.